# How to make a button to show location in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, dictionary, userlocation

This seems like very basic question but I didnt find anything, and I have tried all!! I just want to make a button to zoom in into users location! This is what I've got so far:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocationCoordinate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
        [self.locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];}
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    userLocationCoordinate.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    userLocationCoordinate.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

}

-(IBAction)showUserLocation:(id)sender{

    [self.mapview setCenterCoordinate:userLocationCoordinate animated:YES];

}
```

Please I need help, If theres a way in which I dont use `CLLocationManager` it would be better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need `CLLocationManager` to request location permission from the user,
but you can use the [`setUserTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setUserTrackingMode:animated:) method of `MKMapView` to ask the map view to centre on the user's location.

If you don't want to continue to update the map location as the user moves then you should set the tracking mode to `Follow` and then set it to `None` after a few seconds.

Comment: I didnt know that method (setUserTrackingMode) how is used? because I have implemented it and it does not work

Comment: You might have to set `showsUserLocation` to true as well